# Get options menu to show in system bar

Tags: java, android, menu

I'm trying to get my options menu to show up in the new Android 3.0 system bar. I can get this behavior to work with the Notepadv3 tutorial. However, when implementing nearly the identical functions, the menu shows in the above action bar, but not the system bar. Any ideas?

Attached is the appropriate code for my application:

```
public class AACUser extends Activity {


private static final int ADMIN_ID = Menu.FIRST;

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, ADMIN_ID, 0, R.string.menu_admin);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case ADMIN_ID:
            enterAdminMode();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
}


}
```

I've also tried implementing these menu functions as recomended by the [creating menu documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html):

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.user_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_adminMode:
            enterAdminMode();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

but no difference: it still displays the option in the overflow of the action bar, but not the system bar.

Comment: i tried as dictated in the "creating menu" docs, but to no avail.

Comment: Reducing the targetSdkVersion down to 10 from 11 fixed the problem. However, I want to target this app only to Honeycomb, thus i still don't have permanent solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Android 3.0, the options menu is not required (if not deprecated).  If you target API 11 (Android 3.0) or later, it is assumed that your app will work without an options menu, so the system bar will not display one.  The options menu in the system bar is only there for backwards compatibility with old applications.  New applications should have another affordance for accessing options, such as that provided by the action bar.

Comment: hmm.. i see. I just enjoyed being able to run fullscreen with the options menu button being in the system bar. Anyway to achieve this functionality manually?

Comment: Not if you are targeting API 11 or later.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the menu button in the system bar is for backward compatibility purposes only. So if you want to design your app for Honeycomb then the menu should be and will be in the action bar.