# Android and Honeycomb - how to have a menu icon with SDK 13 without having an "action bar"

Tags: android, menu, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I would like to maximize use of the screen for a Honeycomb app. Since the bottom of the screen is already stuck with "always-on" items, I'd like to add a menu button down there in that space rather than sacrificing more screen space putting an "action bar" across the top. How can I accomplish this *without* downgrading to API 10 or less? (As much as I don't need an action bar using up more space, I also don't need a resize button that does my app no good at all and can't be disabled *except* by going to a very recent API version.)

Surely one can make some kind of effective use of hundreds of pixels that currently sit dark and wasted at the bottom of a Honeycomb screen, between the back/home/thingy icons and that ever-present clock? It'll be a ridiculous waste of yet more space to create an action bar for the purpose of having a single settings button tucked in the corner.

**Edit:** I see others have asked somewhat similar questions but in general, how can we make use of the otherwise wasted space at the bottom by adding buttons or what have you down there? If I have to create my own menu button from scratch I will, but I get the impression that this space is unusable (which would be pretty absurd if true).

**Edit 2:** Apparently it's true: The "system bar" is indeed inviolable and mostly exists to present unoccupied space to the user (particularly in landscape mode). Looks like I may have to revert back to an older SDK - as long as nobody uses the zoom icon it should be fine.

**Edit 3:** I'm pleased to report that with API 10 the menu button is back AND the useless zoom button is GONE (using android:xlargeScreens="true" in the supports-screens appears to work in this API!)

Comment: See my very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688854/honeycomb-themes-noactionbar-or-notitlebar-where-is-menu-button (and lack of useful answers).

Comment: See that upvote you got on your comment there? I did that a little while ago when I found that exact question/answer as I was researching this. The whole thing is kinda ridiculous but whatever, as my app tends to use its own on-screen controls anyway I can readily add my own "menu" icon to them when the time comes. An "action bar" at the top of the screen is IMHO ergonomically weird and virtually useless for my app (which is made to be *easy* to use). Reaching across the screen to hit menu buttons defeats that purpose.